# Laravel Finding difference between dates using Carbon

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

How do I find the difference betwenn start_dt and end_dt which are in the format
 `d M yyy`. eg

> 13 Mar 2017

using Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a pretty dated question but you can simply do

```php
$start_dt = '13 Mar 2017';
$end_dt = '15 Mar 2017';

$diff = Carbon\Carbon::parse($start_dt)->diff(Carbon\Carbon::parse($end_dt));

echo $diff->days;
```